# CreateStreamOnHGlobal() segfault

Tags: c++, windows

I created a stream using [CreateStreamOnHGlobal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378980(v=vs.85).aspx) in order to extract the array of bytes written to it with minimal copying. There are no errors from the stream consumer (which I don't control- it's a WinAPI function) but when I try to access the stream's memory I get a segfault.

```
IStreamPtr ipStream;
CreateStreamOnHGlobal(nullptr, TRUE, &ipStream);

FunctionWhichWritesToIStream(ipStream);

HGLOBAL handle;
GetHGlobalFromStream(ipMemory, &handle);
auto pBytes = static_cast<BYTE *>(handle);

LARGE_INTEGER zero;
zero.QuadPart = 0;
ULARGE_INTEGER nBytes;
ipMemory->Seek(zero, STREAM_SEEK_END, &nBytes);

FunctionWhichReadsFromBytes(pBytes, nBytes); // segfault
```

What am I doing wrong?

NB: I can't use SHCreateMemStream because that does not allow access to the underlying memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the

```
auto pBytes = static_cast<BYTE *>(handle);
```

is error. you need use

```
PBYTE pBytes = (PBYTE)GlobalLock(handle);
```

if want direct access to stream storage. and not forget call `GlobalUnlock` finally

Comment: Thanks. For the benefit of others with my same error: `CreateStreamOnHGlobal(nullptr, TRUE, &ipStream);` allocates a handle to *movable memory*, which is why a pointer must be acquired with GlobalLock instead of just a cast. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366596(v=vs.85).aspx